# Python Multiprocessing Memory Error while processing List of Images

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm in trouble with Python multiprocessing. I am working with the large images size around (1512, 2016) size. Basically what I am trying to do is slicing the images and do some operations on it. Since the image dataset that I am working on is too large. I wanted to create and distribute image pieces to the worker processes than do main calculations. The point that I am getting the error is that after I am reading and slicing all images and putting them onto the queue. When the time comes to the processing those images when I call for the worker processes to start running I am getting this error

```
assignToWorkers()
File "multi.py", line 168, in assignToWorkers
[worker.start() for worker in workers]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 130, in   start
self._popen = Popen(self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 121, in __init__
self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I am started to suspect about the way of I am using python multiprocessing. I need 2 processes work on the pieces and I am basically doing that like this

```
global storage # global queue 
class processclass(multiprocessing.Process):
def __init__(self, datasubset, result_queue):
    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
def run():
    self.datasubset
    # some logic here 



workers = [ processclass(storage.get(), result_queue) for datasubset in range(2) ]   # creating two process from process class
[worker.start() for worker in workers]
[ worker.join() for worker in workers]
```

I am trying to process 500 MB image dataset and have 2 cores and 6gb ram on the virtual machine